# Function parameter meaning in Linux Programming for Pthread Scheduling API

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pthreads

While doing an assignment on Pthread Scheduling API for Operating Systems course. I came across a function which looks like this:

```
   int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

Can someone please explain what does the second last function parameter mean in terms of syntax? i.e.

```
   void *(*start_routine) (void *)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void *(*start_routine) (void *)` is a pointer to a function that takes a `void*` as an argument and returns a `void*`.

Generally, you can use [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) to read complex C declarations. For `void *(*start_routine) (void *)`, it says:

> declare start_routine as pointer to function (pointer to void)
>   returning pointer to void

In Pthreads, the function pointer passed as an argument to `pthread_create()` is the *thread function*, which is run (depending on how OS schedules) after `pthread_create()` call succeeds.

See [here for a simple example](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#CreatingThreads) of how to use `pthread_create()` and the thread function.